# Deriving the wave equation of a variable cross-section rod subjected to non-uniform pressure

Tags: waves, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

On page $519$ of the book *Engineering Vibration* (which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.academia.edu/43145437/Engineering_Vibration_Fourth_Edition)), the following wave equation of a variable cross-section rod is derived:

$${ {\partial}\over{\partial}x} \Big( EA(x){ {\partial}w(x,t)\over{\partial}x}  \Big)={\rho}A(x) { {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{1}$$

where:

- $x$ is the spatial coordinate
- $t$ is time
- $E$ is the Young's modulus of the rod
- $A(x)$ is the variable cross-section function of the rod
- $\rho$ is the density of the rod
- $w(x,t)$ is the wave function

Using Hook's law:

$$P(x,t) = E{ {\partial}w(x,t)\over{\partial}x}\tag{2} $$

where $P(x,t)$ is the pressure applied to the rod's end, we can rewrite equation $(1)$ as:

$${ {\partial}\over{\partial}x} \Big( P(x,t)A(x)\Big)={\rho}A(x) { {\partial}w^2(x,t)\over{\partial}t^2}\tag{3}$$

In the research paper *The Analysis of Longitudinal Impact Response for Variable
Cross-Section Rod* (which can be downloaded from [here](https://ur.booksc.me/book/80042577/cb492b)), an analytical solution to the wave equation $(3)$ is derived. However, the solution is derived based on the assumption that the pressure is distributed uniformly over the whole surface area of the rod's end.

I am trying to derive and solve the wave equation of a variable cross-section rod where the pressure from the impact of a rigid body is not applied uniformly over the rod's ends surface area. I have illustrated this in the picture below.

[image]

I think the wave equations $(1)$ and $(3)$ do not describe the physics of my system correctly. This is because $A(L)$ is not equal to the effective surface area under pressure which is marked as $A_{eff}$ in the picture above.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to derive the correct wave equation that describes the physics of my system. So my questions are:

1. How can I derive the variable cross-section wave equation that takes into consideration a non-uniform pressure distribution at the rod's end?
2. Is there any literature where this is already analyzed and solved?

I need to solve this problem to predict the further dynamics of the system that I am studying. I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! It seems that you may want the general wave equation $\ddot w=c^2\nabla^2 w$, where $c$ is a parameter with units of speed and $\nabla^2$ is the Laplacian, perhaps simplified for this axisymmetric geometry to incorporate only $x$ and the radial distance $r$. This can be expressed in terms of material elastic constants as the [Navier–Cauchy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Elastodynamics_in_terms_of_displacements). Does this get at what you're asking about?

Comment: Hello Chemomechanics. I will try to derive first the Navier-Cauchy equation in order to try to understand it and see if it will describe the physics of my system correctly. I will reply again when I do that. Thank you very much.